# A* search in MATLAB

Tags: search, matlab, a-star

I have implemented A* search in MATLAB, but I am looking for ways to increase the speed and optimize it. I have tried using a priority queue but I found it doesn't work that well, so I am using a different way to implement the search. I will explain the details, so it might get a bit long. I appreciate your patience.

The grid that I am performing the search on is called `workSpace`. I am using the cell indexes, so by checking `workSpace[inx] == 0` I can tell if the cell is occupied or not, `0 -> free` and `1 -> occupied`. This is the main body of the A*. I am passing the work space, the index for the start cell, and the index of the goal cell. As well as the heauristic `h`, and cost `g` functions. `nNodes` is the total number of nodes, which I use to find the successor nodes.

```
function [visitedNodes, f, cameFrom] = aStar(workSpace, startIndx, goalIndx, nNodes, h, g)

    dim = sqrt(nNodes);
    node = startIndx;

    cameFrom(nNodes, 1) = 0;
    cameFrom(node) = node;

    closedSet(nNodes, 1) = 0;
    openSet(nNodes, 1) = 0;

    costSoFar(nNodes, 1) = 0;       

    f = inf(nNodes, 1);

    openSet(node) = 1;
    costSoFar(node) = 0;
    f(node) = 0;

    visitedNodes = 0;

    while sum(openSet) ~= 0
        [~, minFIndx] = min(f);
        f(minFIndx) = inf;
        currentNode = minFIndx;

        if currentNode == goalIndx
            disp('goal Found')
            return
        end

        openSet(currentNode) = 0;
        closedSet(currentNode) = 1;

        childNodes = search.getNeighboursByIndx(workSpace, currentNode, nNodes, dim);

        for i = 1:numel(childNodes)
            if closedSet(childNodes(i)) == 1
                continue
            end

            tentativeGScore = costSoFar(currentNode) + g(currentNode);

            if openSet(childNodes(i)) ~= 1 || tentativeGScore < costSoFar(childNodes(i))     
                cameFrom(childNodes(i)) = currentNode;
                costSoFar(childNodes(i)) = tentativeGScore;
                f(childNodes(i)) = costSoFar(childNodes(i)) + h(childNodes(i));
                if openSet(childNodes(i)) == 0
                    openSet(childNodes(i)) = 1;                    
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

As I mentioned, I am not using a priority queue. I am using the below mechanism to simulate the priority queue.

```
    [~, minFIndx] = min(f);
    f(minFIndx) = inf;
    currentNode = minFIndx;
```

`min` searches through `f`, which is `f = g+h`, and returns the index of the lowest cell and then I set the value of that cell to `inf` so it doesn't come up again in the next round. I use the below function to get the successors, it is also very simple:

```
function successors = getNeighboursByIndx(workSpace, nodeIndx, nNodes, dim)
    delta = [ 1;  dim;... 
             -1; -dim];

    neighbours = bsxfun(@plus, delta, nodeIndx);

    % Create the successor matrix and check if all neighbours are within the grid/freeSpace
    % if not, don't add them to the successors matrix
    successors(4, 1) = 0;

    for i=1:4        
        % (1) the index can't be negative 
        % (2) the index should be smaller than the total number of nodes in the grid
        % (3) the index should not be on the wall around the working space
        %           (1)                         (2)                         (3)
        if (neighbours(i) > 0) && (neighbours(i) <= nNodes) && (mod(neighbours(i), dim) ~= 1) 
            if ~(workSpace(neighbours(i)) == 1) % if the index is not in the wallSpace(1) it is in the freeSpace(0)
                successors(i) = neighbours(i);
            end
        end
    end

    % remove the neighbours that are not eligible as a successor
    % again, `successors` contains the indexes of neighbouring cells
    successors(successors == 0) = [];
end
```

This function is very simple. I use only 4-neighbours, Up(1)-Down(-1) | Right(dim)-Left(-dim).

The current algorithm completes the search on 1681 cells in around `0.05 seconds`. The profiler is telling me that the `getNeighboursByIndx` function takes almost 50% of the total time. In this specific work space it gets called 411 times. Please let me know if it is not clear and you need more information.

**Edit**: I am running the search on a dynamic `workSpace`, the state of a cell is not static and it might change from a free cell to an occupied one or vice-versa. This is the algorithm I am using:

```
set all cells in workSpace to free `0`
while True:
    Check for changes in the workSpace
    if thereIsAChange
        update the workSpace
        perform the search on the new workSpace
    end
end
```

I don't change the state of the `workSpace` during the search. Is it a bad idea?

Comment: Why don't you memoize the neighbours? It seems there's no variation in the connectivity of the items.

Comment: @N74 Actually the reason I am trying to improve the performance is that the workspace is not a static environment and the occupied cells are changing, so I must check for the eligibility of the neighbours. Thanks.

Comment: In this case you can try to make a function to update the neighbours when the workspace changes.

Comment: @N74 That's somehow what I'm doing, but I thought it is not a good idea to change the `workSpace` during the search. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 6):

You say `getNeighboursByIndx` takes 50% of the total time. That means that you should try to reduce either:

1. The number of calls to `getNeighboursByIndx`
2. The time it takes to run `getNeighboursByIndx`

There's a lot of data I don't have, so trying to improve the number of calls to `getNeighboursByIndx` is hard. Improving the performance of the function itself however, should be possible.

If you look at the function you'll see that you are doing a lot of equality checks inside a loop, where only one element at a time is checked against some other value. This is a prime example of something that should be vectorized.

If you use `&` instead of `&&` you can avoid the loop and `if`'s quite simply. From the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html):

> `expr1 && expr2` represents a logical AND operation that employs short-circuiting behavior.

Where as [`&`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html):

> `A & B` performs a logical AND of arrays A and B and returns an array containing elements set to either logical 1 (true) or logical 0 (false).

What you can do here is to create a logical mask, with `true` and `false` in the positions corresponding to the logical conditions, and use that mask to populate `successor`:

```
mask = neighbours > 0 & neighbours <= nNodes & (mod(neighbours, dim) ~= 1) ...
& ~(workSpace(neighbours) == 1)
successors(mask) = neighbours(mask);
```

You can do the same simplification quite easily with the for loop `for i = 1:numel(childNodes)` too.

Also, you don't need to use `bsxfun` when adding scalars to a vector (I'm assuming `nodeIndx` is a scalar).

The `getNeighboursByIndx` function can thus be rewritten as:

```
function successors = getNeighboursByIndx(workSpace, nodeIndx, nNodes, dim)
delta = [ 1;  dim; -1; -dim];
neighbours = delta + nodeIndx;

mask = neighbours > 0 & neighbours <= nNodes & (mod(neighbours, dim) ~= 1) ...
    & ~(workSpace(neighbours) == 1)
    successors = neighbours(mask);

end
```

Much faster, much simpler, and much cleaner! =)

Comment: The index in neighbours might not be in the range so `(workSpace(neighbours) == 1)` might make the code crash. You should   use 2 different masks. But even then it is not faster than the for loop. It's almost twice slower than the for loop.  But it indeed looks nicer.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing that I found is that you are changeing the array size of successor, which you don't need.

Further the map is static during a single search. If it isn't A* can't guarantee optimality, as we are never able to close a node (the path currently concidered best may become blocked during the `while` loop).

Therefore it may make sense to preallocate the neightbours, if the work space has many blocked paths (like a maze). Additionally instead of removing cases where we walk against a wall, just walk to the current position. A* will sort those out for us.

Some micro optimizations (not in any particular order):

- Inline `search.getNeighboursByIndx(workSpace, currentNode, nNodes, dim)` - its not that big and as `search` is an object or struct, it is [painfully slow](http://pastebin.com/nXmZ1tc8) to access.
- `closedSet` and `openSet` are both boolean arrays. Initialize and treat them as such using `false(dimension)` and `true(dimension)` this makes comparisons faster (else the double is "casted" to a boolean every time)
- change the check in the while loop from `sum(openSet) ~= 0` to `any(openSet)` depending on change above. See: [here](http://pastebin.com/264XVwHY)
- do not reaccess `childsNodes(i)` every time. It's marginally faster to store it in a variable and reference that one.
- if you have a LOT (say over 100k) nodes, then `max()` will be outperformed by a priority queue if you use a heap as backbone ( O(n) for max and O(log(n)) for heap). However I don't know of any pure matlab implementation of a heap. DO NOT use `sort()` for the queue. That is O(n*log(n)) (Quick Sort implementation) and really hurts.

I couldn't get the code to display as one large block in this post. So here is the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1wLmPziM) version. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Matlab is implementing quick sort, [see here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96656-what-type-of-sort-does-the-sort-function-in-matlab-perform)